# how to pass value to var upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to pass/add the value of variables *ruby, diamond, emerald,* and *bloodstone* to the variable *totalScore* upon each click. I've added event listeners for each of the buttons but nothing happens when the buttons are clicked. Should I be using some variation of "return" to accomplish this?

I've included the javascript, html and css.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var totalScore = 0;
  console.log(totalScore);

  var ruby = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(ruby);
  var diamond = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(diamond);
  var emerald = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(emerald);
  var bloodstone = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(bloodstone);

  var targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  $("#totalScore").html(totalScore + ruby);


  $("#ruby").click(function() {
    totalScore = totalScore + ruby;
  })
  return ("totalScore");

  $("#diamond").click(function() {
    totalScore = totalScore + diamond;
  })
  console.log("totalScore");

  $("#emerald").click(function() {
    totalScore = totalScore + emerald;
  })
  console.log("totalScore");

  $("#bloodstone").click(function() {
    totalScore = totalScore + bloodstone;
  })
  console.log("totalScore");
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #D2B48C;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 320px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!--
    javascript

    Crystals: Ruby, Diamond, Emerald, Blodstone
        value between 1-10
        each click adds crystal value to totalScore

    targetNumber
        randomly generated

    totalScore
        sum of crystal clicks
    
    WinsLosses
        If totalScore = targetNumber + 1 Win and Reset
        If totalScore > targetNumber + 1 Loss and Reset
    -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Crystal Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="totalScore" rows="4" cols="50"> 
                    "Your total score equals" 
                    </textarea> (totalScore)
  <button type="button" id="ruby">Ruby</button>

  <button type="button" id="diamond">Diamond</button>

  <button type="button" id="emerald">Emerald</button>

  <button type="button" id="bloodstone">Bloodstone</button>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="assets/javaScript/crystal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post HTML code please?

Comment: `return ("totalScore");` exists.  Any logic after it will not execute.  As such the bindings on diamond, emerald, bloodstone will not happen.

Comment: Thank you. I removed that line of code and replaced it with console.log("totalScore")    but the buttons still do not add value to "totalScore" for some reason....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `$("#totalScore").html(totalScore + ruby);` in every `click` action.
Following is the corrected code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Crystal Game</title>
  
  <style>
   body {
    background: #D2B48C;
  }

  ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 320px;
  }

  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <textarea id="totalScore" rows="4" cols="50"> 
     "Your total score equals" 
     </textarea> (totalScore)
 <button type="button" id="ruby">Ruby</button>

 <button type="button" id="diamond">Diamond</button>

 <button type="button" id="emerald">Emerald</button>

 <button type="button" id="bloodstone">Bloodstone</button>


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" 
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  var totalScore = 0;
  console.log(totalScore);

  var ruby = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(ruby);
  var diamond = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(diamond);
  var emerald = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(emerald);
  var bloodstone = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log(bloodstone);

  var targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  $("#totalScore").html(totalScore + ruby);
  
  $("#ruby").click(function() {
  totalScore = totalScore + ruby;
  console.log("totalScore");
  $("#totalScore").html(totalScore + ruby);
  });

  $("#diamond").click(function() {
  totalScore = totalScore + diamond;
  console.log("totalScore");
  $("#totalScore").html(totalScore + diamond);
  });

  $("#emerald").click(function() {
  totalScore = totalScore + emerald;
  console.log("totalScore");
  $("#totalScore").html(totalScore + emerald);
  });

  $("#bloodstone").click(function() {
  totalScore = totalScore + bloodstone;
  console.log("totalScore");
  $("#totalScore").html(totalScore + bloodstone);
  });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```